# React Native, State Changes, but JSX Conditional Rendering Does not Updated UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Hello and thank you for your time in advance!

I am struggling with a small issue that I have not encountered before, with React not rendering an UI element based on a check function. Basically, what I am trying to make, is a multiple selection filter menu, where when an option is clicked, the dot next to it changes to red.

For this purpose I append the value of each option to an array, and using array.sort, verify when it is to be added (value is pushed to FilterList) and removed (value is popped from FilterList)

The checkfilter function operates normally, and when logging the state, indeed it works as intended with the array being updated.

However, the JSX code running the checkfilter to render the extra red dot inside the bigger circle, unfortunately does not.

Additionally, when the screen is refreshed, the UI is updated normally, with every option clicked, now showing the aforementioned red dot.

Why is this happening? I have tried several hooks, JSX approaches, using imported components and more that I can't even remember, yet the UI will not update oddly.

Below you can find a snippet of the code. Please bear in mind this is a render function for a flatlist component

```
    const checkFilter = useCallback((element) => {
    return filterList?.some((el: any) => (el == element))
}, [filterList])
const removeFilter = useCallback((cat) => {
    let temparr = filterList
    var index = temparr?.indexOf(cat);
    if (index > -1) {
        temparr?.splice(index, 1);
    }
    setFilterList(temparr)
}, [filterList])
const addFilter = useCallback((cat) => {
    let temparr = filterList;
    temparr.push(cat);
    setFilterList(temparr)
}, [filterList])

const renderFilter = useCallback((item) => {
    return (

        <Pressable
            onPress={() => {
                checkFilter(item?.item) ? removeFilter(item?.item) : addFilter(item?.item);
                console.log(filterList)
            }}
            style={styles.modalOptionWrapper}
        >
            <Text style={styles.modalOptionTitle(checkFilter)}>{item?.item}</Text>
            <View style={styles.modalOptionRowRight}>
                <View style={styles.radioBtn}>
                    {checkFilter(item?.item) ?
                        <View style={styles.radioBtnBullet} />
                        :
                        null
                    }
                </View>
            </View>

        </Pressable>

    )
}, [filterList])
```

Comment: is the `renderFilter` being called on update?

Comment: I have some advices. First, remove all `useCallback` and see your UI changes. Second, add some console.log(some_value) in your codes to know the list really changed or not. If not work all, remove all codes and start with a clean basic. Just filterList and its map function. What I mean is start with a simple codes, then, add more features one by one when your codes work.

Comment: @Four I did run logs, and indeed it does log the array properly. Have tried removing all callbacks to no avail unfortunately.

As for clean build, rather difficult, it is a quite complicated project but might as well try if all else fails :/

Comment: `const checkFilter = useCallback((element) => {
    return filterList?.some((el: any) => (el == element))
}, [filterList])` is not returning JSX elements. Use `useMemo`.

Comment: @Four Haven't tried that, rarely use useMemo, mind me asking, since it doesn't take arguments like useCallback, how would I pass the item?

Comment: I cannot explain in details. `useCallback` is used for functions. `useMemo` is used for a value that comes from a complex function. It memoizes the value and it does not undergo complex function again unless dependencies are not changed. Every state has previous state props. If you want to update previous state, you don't need current state. For example, a boolean value. `setState(!state)` is bad. `setState(prev=> !prev)` is good. You should read about spread iterator too. It makes our codes clean and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be correct answer but try this. When I say simple basic codes, like this.

```
const ListItems = () => {
  const [filterList, setFilterList] = React.useState([]); // must be array

  const checkFilter = filterList?.some((el) => el === element);
  const removeFilter = useCallback(
    (cat) => {
      // not updating new state, just useing previous state
      setFilterList((prev) => [...prev].filter((el) => el !== cat));
      // used spread iterator
    },
    [] // no need dependency
  );
  const addFilter = useCallback((cat) => {
    // used spread indicator
    setFilterList((prev) => [...prev, cat]);
  }, []);

  const renderFilter = useCallback((item) => {
    // just checking our codes is right with basic elements
    // it may be 'undefined'
    return <Text>{JSON.stringify(item)}</Text>;
  }, []);

  return filterList.map(renderFilter);
};
```

Comment: Sadly, it did not yield any result, but I very much appreciate your time and effort!

( I did very slight adjustments to fit the logic of the overall app and screen but core functionality was the same )